# Switch form full screen to windowed mode using Esc

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I have done some digging and found some code that can run the application directly to full-screen mode during runtime, I was wondering if there is any way to switch back to windowed mode by **pressing "Esc"** ?

Here is my code for full-screen mode:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
    Topmost = true;
    WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered adding a PreviewKeyDown event handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set  `this.KeyPreview = true;`

And  `this.KeyDown += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(Form_KeyDown);`

```
    private void Form_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Escape)
        {
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think the `WindowState` should be `Normal`, he said he wanted it "windowed", not minimized.